# Value in JSON does not display in tableviewcell custom

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3

Can't display data in TableViewCell.Data reports of events, but the when you open the array "sports" display the data in cels no.The display of the title occurs and the transfer is ended...

This is my json code...

```
Event.swift


    import UIKit

    struct Event {
        let match : String
        let forecast : String
        let data : String
        let image : UIImage
        var sports : [Sport]

        init (match : String, forecast : String, data: String, image : UIImage, sports : [Sport]) {

        self.match = match
        self.forecast = forecast
        self.data = data
        self.image = image
        self.sports = sports


      }

        static func eventsFromBundle ()-> [Event] {

            var events = [Event] ()


            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "events", withExtension: "json") else {
                return events
            }
                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                    guard let rootObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : Any]  else {

                        return events
                    }

                    guard let eventObjects = rootObject["events"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
                        return events
                    }
                    for eventObject in eventObjects {
                        if let match = eventObject["match"] as? String,
                            let forecast = eventObject["forecast"]  as? String,
                            let data = eventObject["data"] as? String,
                            let imageName = eventObject["image"] as? String,
                            let image = UIImage(named: imageName),
                            let sportsObject = eventObject["sports"] as? [[String : String]]{
                            var sports = [Sport]()
                            for sportObject in sportsObject {
                              if let  nameTitle = sportObject["name"] ,
                                    let titleName = sportObject["image"],
                                    let titleImage = UIImage(named: titleName + ".jpg"),
                                    let prognozLabel = sportObject["prognoz"],
                                    let obzor = sportObject["obzor"] {
                                sports.append(Sport(name: nameTitle, prognoz: prognozLabel, image: titleImage, obzor: obzor, isExpanded: false))

                                }
                            }

                            let event = Event(match: match, forecast: forecast, data: data, image: image, sports: sports)
                            events.append(event)

                        }
                    }


                } catch {
                    return events
            }

            return events
        }

    }

import UIKit

class SportViewController: BaseViewController {

    var events = Event.eventsFromBundle ()


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange, object: .none, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] _ in
           self?.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }


        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SportDetailViewController,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destination.selectedEvent = events[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}



extension SportViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count
 }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellMatch", for: indexPath) as! SportTableViewCell

    let event = events[indexPath.row]
    cell.matchLabel.text = event.match
    cell.imageMatch.image = event.image
    cell.forecastLabel.text = event.forecast
    cell.dataLabel.text = event.data

    cell.matchLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
    cell.forecastLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .callout)
    return cell

    }
}
```

Her is the controller.SportDetailViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SportDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedEvent : Event!



    let obzorText = "Select for more info >"

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = selectedEvent.match
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
           }
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)


            }

    }



 extension SportDetailViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
     {
        return selectedEvent.sports.count

    }



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell : SportDetailTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellMatch", for: indexPath) as! SportDetailTableViewCell

            let sport = selectedEvent.sports[indexPath.row]


            cell.nameTitle.text = sport.name
            cell.titleImage.image = sport.image
            cell.prognozLabel.text = sport.prognoz
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.nameTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

            cell.obzorText.text = sport.isExpanded ? sport.obzor : obzorText
            cell.obzorText.textAlignment = sport.isExpanded ? .left : .center

            return cell
}
   }



 extension SportDetailViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SportDetailTableViewCell else { return }

        var sport = selectedEvent.sports[indexPath.row]

        sport.isExpanded = !sport.isExpanded
        selectedEvent.sports[indexPath.row] = sport

        cell.obzorText.text = sport.isExpanded ? sport.obzor : obzorText
        cell.obzorText.textAlignment = sport.isExpanded ? .left : .center


        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

    }

}
```

all these methods have tried: tableview.datasource = self , tableview.delegate = self и reloadData().....in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Yes.Why what did I do wrong?I did on the lesson of becoming self-size RayWenderlinch.Can help to correct the error?

Comment: Where did you load your events data in your `SportDetailViewController` ?

Comment: I have another controller of the data events are loaded.I have displayed data "events".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this `init` from your `struct`: (because `struct` gets free initializer)

```
init (match : String, forecast : String, data: String, image : UIImage, sports : [Sport]) {

    self.match = match
    self.forecast = forecast
    self.data = data
    self.image = image
    self.sports = sports
}
```

Now, your `var events` won't be populated as you are calling method in class scope. So change this:

```
class SportViewController: BaseViewController {

    var events = Event.eventsFromBundle ()
    ...
    ...
}
```

to

```
class SportViewController: BaseViewController {

    var events = [Event]()
    ...
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100

        events = Event().eventsFromBundle()
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: See my edit and delete `static` from here: `static func eventsFromBundle ()`

Comment: delete the `static` keyword only, not the whole line.

Comment: Okay, have you deleted that `init()` method? Have you changed `var events = Event.eventsFromBundle ()` to `var events = [Event]()`? And have you added `events = Event().eventsFromBundle()` inside your `viewDidLoad()` method of `SportViewController` class??

Comment: Let's do one thing. You upload your project somewhere and give the link. You might have problems elsewhere.

Comment: Okay I'll let you know. Right now I'm in the way of installing Xcode :(